# Getting User custom permission in Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, custom-permission

I need to check if the running user has a specific custom permission in their profile within my flow logic.
How can I check that?

Answer (score 4):

You can refer custom permission in workflows, ProcessBuilder and Visualworkflow using $Permission.

If the name of my custom permission is Enable_Contact_Creation, then to refer it in formula it will be

```
$Permission.Enable_Contact_Creation
```

Src :https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221057&type=1

https://automationchampion.com/2017/06/29/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-70-bypass-process-for-a-specific-user-or-profile/#more-12306

Comment: That I know, but how do I know if the running user has this custom permission added to his profile or directly?

Comment: Please edit the question and put this details... Your question currently is being interpret as someonething else